# Как передать заранее неизвестное количество аргументов в функцию

Tags: golang

Нужно обработать SQL SELECT запрос, я не знаю сколько мне придёт столбцов, как можно передавать в функцию Scan пакета database/sql произвольное количество аргументов? можно конечно сделать так, но слишком коряво выглядит:

```
switch len(columns) {
case 1:
    rows.Scan(&interfaces[0])
case 2:
    rows.Scan(&interfaces[0], &interfaces[1])
case 3:
    rows.Scan(&interfaces[0], &interfaces[1], &interfaces[2])
...
}
```

Такой вариант тоже не работает:

```
interfaces := make([]*string, 0, len(coltype))
for range interfaces{
    var str string
    interfaces = append(interfaces, &str)
}
rows.Next()
rows.Scan(interfaces...)
```

Ошибка

> cannot use interfaces (type []*string) as type []interface {} in
>   argument to rows.Scan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то типа:

```golang
args := []interface{}{&foo, &bar, &baz}

// ...

err = rows.Scan(args...)
```

---

Более подробное объяснение. Внутри `args []interface{}` должны находиться *указатели.* Если у вас ожидается одна колонка, то:

```golang
var foo string

// ...

// N.B. Тип «args» — «[]interface{}»; внутри — указатель.
var args = []interface{}{&foo}

// ...

err = rows.Scan(args...)
```

Если у вас срез строк, то должно быть что-то типа:

```golang
var foos []string

// ...

var args = make([]interface{}, len(foos))
for i := range foos {
    // N.B. Берём указатели каждой строки.
    args[i] = &foos[i]
}

// ...

err = rows.Scan(args...)
```

Comment: Пробовал, возвращает nil'ы. Нужно именно ссылку передавать в функцию.

Comment: Если вы передавали указатели на данные внутри интерфесов, всё должно работать. Напишите в вопрос код, подобный моему, который у вас не работает.

Comment: Дописал Ваш код в вопрос вместе с ошибкой

Comment: См. правку. Должно стать понятнее.

Comment: Да, получилось, спасибо. Если не сложно - можете объяснить/дать ссылку на материал/подсказать темы для прочтения чтобы понять, почему вариант с append не сработал?

Comment: Конкретно про этот случай документации нету. Тут пересечение [правил конвертации](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) и [законов отражения](https://blog.golang.org/laws-of-reflection).